# (Simple) constructors in variadic template classes

Tags: c++, syntax, c++11, variadic-templates

How would a constructor and a copy constructor look for this variadic template class?

```
struct A {};
struct B {};

template < typename Head,
           typename... Tail>
struct X : public Head,
           public Tail...
{
    X(int _i) : i(_i) { }

    // add copy constructor

    int i;
};

template < typename Head >
struct X<Head> { };

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    X<A, B> x(5);
    X<A, B> y(x);

    // This must not be leagal!
    // X<B, A> z(x);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template < typename Head,
           typename... Tail>
struct X : public Head,
           public Tail...
{
    X(int _i) : i(_i) { }

    // add copy constructor
    X(const X& other) : i(other.i) {}

    int i;
};
```

Inside the template class, `X` as a type means `X<Head, Tail...>`, and all `X` with different template parameters are distinct types, so the copy constructor of `X<A,B>` won't match `X<B,A>`.

Demo: http://ideone.com/V6g35